# How to set the path to custom Firefox profile during geckodriver startup?

Tags: webdriver, geckodriver

First roadbump - no Selenium, only simple curl commands. I successfully launch the driver instance using the following request:

```
curl --data '{"capabilities":{"browserName":"firefox","firefoxOptions":{"args":["-profile","D:\\path\\to\\folder"]},"platformName":"windows"}}' http://localhost:4444/session
```

After that everything works as intended, except that Firefox profile is created in the default location somewhere in %APPDATA%/Roaming instead of the desired D:/path/to/folder. What am I doing wrong?